# How to implement ladda-bootstrap button loading animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Here's the github documentation: https://github.com/msurguy/ladda-bootstrap

I'm trying to make my code work but for some reason, the ladda won't stop spinning (button never gets enabled again), EVEN if I place "Ladda.stopAll();" after the AJAX call. Here's my code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success ladda-button" data-style="expand-left" id="genPDF"><span class="ladda-label">Generate PDF</span></button>

<script>

    Ladda.bind('button[id=genPDF]');

    $('#genPDF').click(function () {

        //Another approach I tried
        //Ladda.bind(this);

        var str = "tmName=" + $("#tmName").val() +
            "&headingText=" + $("#headingText").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "testing.php",
            data: str,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                //None of this code matters, it all works fine
                console.log(data);
                var container = document.getElementById("pdfContainer");
                var content = container.innerHTML;
                container.innerHTML = content;
            }
        });

        //If I placed Ladda.stopAll(); here, the ladda wouldn't even
        //START spinning upon being clicked on.
    });

</script>
```

Comment: I'm curious why you used `button[id=genPDF]` instead of `button#genPDF`

Comment: @amflare I went ahead and replaced with "button#genpdf". But this still doesn't help me with solving the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is your problem

```
Ladda.bind('button[id=genPDF]');
```

**Docs:**

> // Automatically trigger the loading animation on click
>
> Ladda.bind('input[type=submit]' );
>
> // Same as the above but automatically stops after two seconds
>
> Ladda.bind( 'input[type=submit]', { timeout: 2000 } );

When it says "Automatically trigger the loading animation on click", it does literally that. It loads it, which leads it to just keep running because you never gave told it to stop.

Comment: I'm trying to make it stop instantly after the completion of everything inside the ajax call, not just based on a timeout value. putting "Ladda.stopAll();" anywhere at all doesn't even give it the possibility to "start".

Comment: Place the `stopAll()` in the `ajax.success`. Don't forget that the 'A' in 'Ajax' stands for 'Asynchronous', so basically, the JS starts doing the Ajax AND the next code in the file at the same time, giving you about 2 milliseconds that the icon is spinning.

Comment: I tried doing this earlier and just now realized the file I was trying to convert was HUGE so it was taking forever. I went back, adjusted the size ratio, and now it works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

use This it works

```
$('#yourladda_btn').click(function(){
    var l = Ladda.create(this);
    l.start();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'test.php',
        type: "post",
        data: {"yourdata":"test"},
        success: function(){

        }

    }).always(
            function() {
                l.stop();
            }
    );
});
```

Comment: i would recommand to add `e.preventDefault();` before `var l = Ladda.create(this);`